# How to track attendance based on a schedule in a SQL model for a FastAPI based Attendace Marking System

Tags: python, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need help with an SQL Model design, trying to create an API for an application that automatically marks attendance of teachers once they enter a class room.

Admins can add schedules for staff members/teachers, which will be nothing but class timings.

A class/schedule can be a single time one, or reoccurring as well.

Below is my model:

```
class ScheduleModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "schedules"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    staff_member_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), unique=True, nullable=False
    )
    location_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("locations.id"), unique=True, nullable=False
    )

    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_reoccuring = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    # Date will be null for reoccuring classes
    date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
    day = Column(Enum(DaysEnum), nullable=False)
    start_time = Column(Time, nullable=False)
    end_time = Column(Time, nullable=False)

    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, onupdate=func.now())


class AttendanceModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attendances"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

Now the problem is that how do I mark attendance for each class?

I thought of creating a JSON object for each user against their schedule and storing it in `AttendanceModel`, but what if a schedule gets changed in between, then I will have to recreate the entire JSON object, and iterate over previously stored records which will be a huge pain.

Any suggestions will help.

I am trying to use a JSON object as that would make it easier for me to filter out based on class on a particular day, month or week.

Comment: I'm not sure a JSON object would make it easier; having plain fields (and using a datetime field) makes working with the relevant date functions and query predicates (WHERE ...) in SQL far easier. However, what you're looking at seems to be a many-to-many relationship, where you usually have a model in between that contains a foreign key to the schedule, a foreign key to the person (teacher/student) and some associated metadata, such as the timestamp of when the attendance was registered.

Comment: If I have datetime objects in `AttendanceModel` along with a boolean field for attendance, then I will have to create boilerplate objects with did_attend or something set to `False`, and when I get a request from the API, set it to `True` along with timestamps. 

This creates a new set of problems, what if the initial objects have been created for a particular class/schedule with the boolean field for attendance set to False, and the schedule changes (even slightly, such as the day changes), then previously logged timestamps will not match the time for the class.

If this makes sense.

Comment: If you don't want to log when attendance was recorded (i.e. to fit into changing the schedule), don't have a datetime field. You don't need a true/false value: if there is a row, attendance was registered. If there is no row, no attendance was registered. So there is no need to store all entries with a False entry - just no attendance being registered for the scheduled event as the default.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I thought about this but was confused on how to get attendance for user for a particular day. In order to do that I need timestamps.

The only solution that I feel is to create an individual instance for each reoccurring schedule, and then have the attendance logged for that.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to have an instance for each actual class, you can't just have the class and the schedule for the coming week. You then link that instance of the class (i.e. the session) to the user and attach a datetime for when they were registered. You can then generate attendance records, know whether people show up at time or late, create statistics based on when the class is held and whether people are later to class in the morning than evening, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am going to do now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256266/discussion-between-syed-azeem-javed-and-matslindh).